# get specific data from URL in android/java?

Tags: java, android, url, urldecode

I have a url like this

https://example.com%3A443:443/www/36d8e8c94aae45048ba9f92f8e62c7b2/file/content?path=%2Fmnt%2Fsdcard%2Fvideo%2Fsample_mpeg4.mp4&yyy=9a7491a1f5664336b5c6bf431f42852c3749ed54722736ec748746858a710c44

I need to get the path of file as /mnt/sdcard/video from the URL . How do i do that ?
I used URL decoder to remove the spaces but i am confused on getting the path of the file . 
Thanks for all your help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use [Uri.getQueryParameter()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/Uri.html#getQueryParameter%28java.lang.String%29).

```
import android.net.Uri;

Uri uri = Uri.parse("https://example.com%3A443:443/www/36d8e8c94aae45048ba9f92f8e62c7b2/file/content?path=%2Fmnt%2Fsdcard%2Fvideo%2Fsample_mpeg4.mp4&yyy=9a7491a1f5664336b5c6bf431f42852c3749ed54722736ec748746858a710c44");
String pathParam = uri.getQueryParameter("path");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with [the `Uri` class](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/Uri.html). Construct a `Uri` object and use `Uri.getQueryParameter()`.